# Dynamics CRM 2013 : Report for team's users

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to retrieve (in report or view) all users that are in a specific team, or get all teams with their users.
CRM 2013 on premise.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to Settings - Administration - Teams and then change the view selector to "All Teams".  Then once there, you can open the teams and will be able to see the users who are a member of the team in the "Team Members" list.  If you want to use a report, since you are using OnPremise, you could use either a SQL query to get User and Team information, or alternatively could create a FetchXML based report that could also be used in CRM Online (if you later decide to move to CRM Online, then the FetchXML will be the only way to get the custom report to work).  I just picked some of the basic columns, but you could add as needed additional columns from these views.

```
SELECT     tm.SystemUserId, tm.TeamId, tm.TeamMembershipId, su.DomainName,T.Name
FROM         dbo.FilteredTeamMembership tm
INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser Su on tm.SystemUserID = Su.SystemUserId 
INNER JOIN FilteredTeam T on Tm.TeamId = T.TeamId
ORDER BY T.Name
```

or FetchXML below:

```
<fetch mapping="logical">
<entity name="TeamMembership">
<attribute name="SystemUserId" />
<attribute name="TeamId" />
<attribute name="TeamMembershipId" />
<link-entity name="SystemUser" to="SystemUserID" from="SystemUserId" alias="Su" link-type="inner">
  <link-entity name="Team" to="TeamId" from="TeamId" alias="T" link-type="inner">
    <attribute name="Name" />
    <order attribute="T" />
  </link-entity>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```